# pytesseract not working in python eventhough path is set

Tags: python, tesseract

I am trying to install a package Pytesseract-OCR in anaconda prompt and I am facing the following issue.
Below are the steps I followed

```
pip install pillow
pip install pytesseract
```

Then I downloaded pytesseract-ocr from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki and installed the same to F: directory

When I tried to run the python code in my Jupyter notebook as below:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'F:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
im=Image.open(r"G:\Downloads From Chrome\myimg.jpg")
result=pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

It is throwing the below error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help me to resolve the issue
Thank you in advance

Thank you for solving the above issue
I tried but it has resulted in another issue

```
(1, 'Error opening data file F:\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata/english.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'english\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

I have also set the path F:\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata in my system environment variable as TESSDATA_PREFIX and restarted as well but even then it is not working. I have all english file in my directory mentioned above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to also use raw `r""` strings with the path.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'F:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Otherwise, that `\t` there is interpreted as a tab character, and `F:\Tesseract-OCR        esseract.exe` surely doesn't exist :)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. It has solved the issue but gave rise to new error . I will just update in the actual question